# Add and subtract 1 hour from Timestamp column in DBeaver (SQL)

Tags: sql, timestamp, vertica, dbeaver

I have a table with the column 'Timestamp'. I want to create 2 columns that contains the -1hour and +1hour of that time stamp.

This is the format of the timestamp: 2020-08-31 11:05:55
and I want to get 2 more columns showing the -1hour and +1hour: 2020-08-31 10:05:55 and 2020-08-31 12:05:55

Thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi sorry, I'm not very familiar with the terms but I am connecting to Vertica. Is that the DBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard ANSI SQL you can simply subtract an interval:

```
select the_column - interval '1' hour as one_hour_before,
       the_column, 
       the_column + interval '1' hour as one_hour_after
from the_table
where ....
```

Answer (score 1):

a_horse_with_no_name is right. The standard way is to add/subtract INTERVALs.

However Vertica date arithmetics offers some very simple *shortcuts*...

When you add/subtract an INTEGER value it is interpreted as number of **days**:

```
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-1;
           ?column?            |           ?column?            |           ?column?            
-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 2020-09-03 00:38:54.781675-04 | 2020-09-04 00:38:54.781675-04 | 2020-09-02 00:38:54.781675-04
```

If you want to add/subtract:

- **hours** you have to use 1/24,
- **minutes** you have to use 1/1440
- **seconds** you have to use 1/86400.

For example:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+1/24, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-1/24;
           ?column?            |           ?column?            |           ?column?            
-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 2020-09-03 00:38:54.781675-04 | 2020-09-03 01:38:54.781675-04 | 2020-09-02 23:38:54.781675-04

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+1/1440, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-1/1440;
           ?column?            |           ?column?            |           ?column?            
-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 2020-09-03 00:38:54.781675-04 | 2020-09-03 00:39:54.781675-04 | 2020-09-03 00:37:54.781675-04
```

Answer (score 0):

DATEADD()][1](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp) might be your best bet if your DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server. If you are using something like Oracle, the ANSI interval solution by a_horse_with_no_name is a great, easy to read, option.

For example the below code yields,

```
SELECT '2020-08-31 11:05:55' AS time_stamp, 
   DATEADD(hour, 1, '2020-08-31 11:05:55') plus_one_hour, 
   DATEADD(hour, -1, '2020-08-31 11:05:55') minus_one_hour;
```

--OUTPUT

```
      plus_one_hour              time_stamp                minus_one_hour
'2020-08-31 12:05:55.000'   '2020-08-31 11:05:55.000'     '2020-08-31 10:05:55.000'
```